# How to compare and sort subclasses?

Tags: c#, sorting, compare, subclass

For example I have these class and subclasses.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new List<Animal> { new Wolf {kills = 5}, 
                                         new Rabbit {name = "Uncle John"}, 
                                         new Eagle {eyeCount = 1}, 
                                         new Wolf {kills = 100}, 
                                         new Rabbit { name = "Human" } };
        animals.Sort();
//Suposted to be: Rabbit(Human), Rabbit(Uncle John), Wolf(5), Wolf(100), Eagle(1)
    }
}

enum SortOrder { Rabbit, Wolf, Eagle }

abstract class Animal{}
class Wolf : Animal
{
    public int kills = 0; //Marked public for simple initialization
}
class Rabbit : Animal
{
    public string name = "Funny Little Guy"; //Marked public for simple initialization
}
class Eagle : Animal
{
    public byte eyeCount = 2; //Marked public for simple initialization
}
```

I want to sort list of animals. 1)Sort among the other objects of same type (sort Wolves by kill, rabbits by name, etc) 2) Sort groups of subclasses in "SortOrder", so Rabbits goes first in the list and Eagles last.

I had tried make this by implementing `IComparable<Animal>, IComparable<Wolf>, IComparable<Rabbit>, IComparable<Eagle>` interfaces, but this lead me to nowhere, because I couldn't make this work and even though I could, adding 1 more subclass cause a lot code work.

This is my trying:

```
abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>, IComparable<Wolf>, IComparable<Rabbit>, IComparable<Eagle>
{
    public abstract int CompareTo(Animal other);
    public abstract int CompareTo(Wolf other);
    public abstract int CompareTo(Rabbit other);
    public abstract int CompareTo(Eagle other);
}

class Wolf : Animal
{
    public int kills = 0; //Marked public for simple initialization

    public override int CompareTo(Animal other) => other.CompareTo(this);
    public override int CompareTo(Wolf other) => kills.CompareTo(kills);
    public override int CompareTo(Rabbit other) => SortOrder.Wolf.CompareTo(SortOrder.Rabbit);
    public override int CompareTo(Eagle other) => SortOrder.Wolf.CompareTo(SortOrder.Eagle);
}
```

But by doing this way I getting reverse order, and As I said its hard to add new subclasses.

So what is efficient way to make this kind of comparison?

Comment: Share your attempted code (The IComparable's)

Answer (score 2):

To minimize adding new code and force new class to add to the hierarchy I would do this kind of design:

First, I would implement IComparable for each concrete animal type. This is simple. Second, I would add SortOrder OrderType property to the abstract class and implement it in each concrete instance. This would force whoever extends the class to re-evaluate the enum and probably add new value to it. Then, the main compare function would first check this property. If not equal, then return the comparison between types. If equal, just call compare on the two instances, because it can be safely assumed they are of same type.

Implemented it here. I actually had to use reflection, because there is no other way to call concrete comparer. But it seems to work pretty nicely, as long as the actual type corresponds to returned enum.

```
enum SortOrder { Rabbit, Wolf, Eagle }

abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>
{
    public abstract SortOrder OrderType { get; }

    public int CompareGeneric(Animal x, Animal y)
    {
        // use reflection to call comparer on concrete animal type
        var comparerType = typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(x.GetType());
        var compareMethod = comparerType.GetMethod("CompareTo");

        return (int)compareMethod.Invoke(x, new object[] { y });
    }

    public int Compare(Animal x, Animal y)
    {
        // clever hack to compare the enums
        var diff = x.OrderType - y.OrderType;
        if (diff != 0)
            return diff;

        return CompareGeneric(x, y);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Animal other)
    {
        return Compare(this, other);
    }
}

class Wolf : Animal, IComparable<Wolf>
{
    public override SortOrder OrderType { get { return SortOrder.Wolf; } }

    public int kills = 0; //Marked public for simple initialization

    public int CompareTo(Wolf other)
    {
        return this.kills.CompareTo(other.kills);
    }
}
class Rabbit : Animal, IComparable<Rabbit>
{
    public override SortOrder OrderType { get { return SortOrder.Rabbit; } }

    public string name = "Funny Little Guy"; //Marked public for simple initialization

    public int CompareTo(Rabbit other)
    {
        return this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
    }
}
class Eagle : Animal, IComparable<Eagle>
{
    public override SortOrder OrderType { get { return SortOrder.Eagle; } }

    public byte eyeCount = 2; //Marked public for simple initialization

    public int CompareTo(Eagle other)
    {
        return this.eyeCount.CompareTo(other.eyeCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement IComparable with Animal class and use a read only SortOrder enum property as Euphoric mentioned.
Then in each class you can override CompareTo method to compare each species with their kind.

```
    public abstract class Animal : IComparable
    {
        public abstract SortOrder SortOrder { get; }

        public virtual int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Animal rightValue = (Animal)obj;
            return this.SortOrder < rightValue.SortOrder ? -1
                : this.SortOrder > rightValue.SortOrder ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    public class Wolf : Animal
    {
        public override SortOrder SortOrder { get { return SortOrder.Wolf; } }
        public int kills = 0; //Marked public for simple initialization
        public override int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Wolf)
            {
                Wolf rightValue = (Wolf)obj;
                return this.kills < rightValue.kills ? -1
                    : this.kills > rightValue.kills ? 1 : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.CompareTo(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Rabbit : Animal
    {
        public override SortOrder SortOrder { get { return SortOrder.Rabbit; } }
        public string name = "Funny Little Guy"; //Marked public for simple initialization

        public override int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Rabbit)
            {
                Rabbit rightValue = (Rabbit)obj;
                return String.Compare(this.name, rightValue.name);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.CompareTo(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Eagle : Animal
    {
        public override SortOrder SortOrder { get { return SortOrder.Eagle; } }
        public byte eyeCount = 2; //Marked public for simple initialization
        public override int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Eagle)
            {
                Eagle rightValue = (Eagle)obj;
                return this.eyeCount < rightValue.eyeCount ? -1
                    : this.eyeCount > rightValue.eyeCount ? 1 : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.CompareTo(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an SortKey and the ICompareable Interface to your Animal class and implement the logic in derived class.

```
    abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>
    {
        public abstract int SortKey { get; }

        public abstract int CompareTo(Animal other);
    }
    class Wolf : Animal
    {
        public int kills = 0; //Marked public for simple initialization

        public override int SortKey { get { return 100; } }
        public override int CompareTo(Animal other)
        {
            if (other.SortKey != SortKey)
            {
                return SortKey.CompareTo(other.SortKey);
            }

            var otherWolf = other as Wolf;

            if (otherWolf == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return kills.compareTo(otherWolf.kills);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem I see with this implementation that you have to have key comparison in every concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) *across* types; and implement IComparable for ordering *within* the specific type. The Comparer would call the Comparable only for same-type comparisons.

Advantage(s):

- None of the types needs to know it's "relative" sorting key between types. In addition the base type is not 'dirtied' with an additional field. (Although there is nothing preventing putting the ordering in such a 'SortKey'-field.)
- The rules for ordering types of animals is isolated in one location, the Comparer.

  The rule for ordering within an animal type is already
  handled by the IComparable and can be overridden/specialized
  for each type.

Disadvantage(s):

- The collection / ordering operation needs to use the Comparer
- Comparer adds "hidden" logic that may need to be updated for additional types. (This is only required if *not* using a 'SortKey'-like approach in a base type.)

Using a separate IComparaer/IComparable approach is a more generic form of using a 'SortKey' field, with the additional ordering mixed into the IComparable, because such a field *could* be used by such a IComparer implementation.

Comment: Disadvantage : Adding new concrete animal doesn't make it clear to add it to the animal comparer. I think it might be breaking LSP.

Comment: Anything that causes code to break when encountering new derived type, without change to the rest of the code, is violation of LSP.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve your Problem with Linq

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

    public enum SortOrder
    {
        Rabbit,
        Wolf,
        Eagle
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animals = (new List<Animal> { new Wolf {Kills = 5},
                                     new Rabbit {Name = "Uncle John"},
                                     new Eagle {EyeCount = 1},
                                     new Wolf {Kills = 100},
                                     new Rabbit { Name = "Human" } })
                            .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                            .ThenBy(x => x.Classifier);

            //Suposted to be: Rabbit(Human), Rabbit(Uncle John), Wolf(5), Wolf(100), Eagle(1)
        }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public abstract object Classifier { get; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class Eagle : Animal
    {
        public Eagle()
        {
            this.SortOrder = SortOrder.Eagle;
        }

        public override object Classifier
        {
            get { return this.EyeCount; }
        }

        public byte EyeCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rabbit : Animal
    {
        public Rabbit()
        {
            this.Name = "Funny Little Guy";
            this.SortOrder = SortOrder.Rabbit;
        }

        public override object Classifier
        {
            get { return this.Name; }
        }
    }

    public class Wolf : Animal
    {
        public Wolf()
        {
            this.Name = "Funny Little Guy";
            this.SortOrder = SortOrder.Wolf;
        }

        public override object Classifier
        {
            get { return this.Kills; }
        }

        public int Kills { get; set; }
    }
```